# How can I close each dropdown straight away, without affecting my delay?

Tags: html, css, navigation

I have a little problem here with my css dropdown navigation.
When I hover over the first item, the dropdown appears, which is good.  And it also has a delay when I mouse away from it, also good.  This is fine as I move all the way across the top level.

However.

If I were to navigate **backwards**, last one, to second last one etc, I notice that the dropdowns are appearing **behind** the one that preceded it.

I am assuming that this is because of the order that they appear on my HTML.

Does anyone have any solutions for this?  CSS or even jQuery is welcome.

I have supplied my code and jsfiddle.

Thanks all for your time!

**EDIT:** I just realised that my delay isn't ideal.  I can mouse away from the subnav, and it stays for a few seconds, but when I mouse back into it again, it isn't clickable.  Probably due to the `pointer-events:none`

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4wLtmx9m/

```
#menu {
    position: relative;
}
#navbar {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
}
#navbar li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    width: 16.6%;
    background-color: #F6F6F6;
    text-align: center;
    color:#9a9999;
    /*background:url(../Assets/icons/nav-sprite-icons.png)0 20px;*/
}
#navbar li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 8px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#navbar li a:hover {
    color: #000;
}
#navbar li ul {
    opacity:0;
    top:0px;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:black;
    z-index: -100;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    pointer-events:none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease 3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease 1s;
}
#navbar li ul li {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
}
#navbar li ul li a {
    color:white!important;
}
#navbar li:hover ul {
    opacity:1;
    background-color:black;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline;
    top:22px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index:-100;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
    /*animation: fadein 0.2s;
    -webkit-animation: fadein 0.2s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 0.2s;*/
    pointer-events:auto;
}
#navbar * {
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
#navbar li:hover li, #navbar li.hover li {
    float: left;
    background-color:black;
}
#navbar li:hover li a, #navbar li.hover li a {
    color: #FFF;
}
#navbar li li a:hover {
    color: #357;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul id="navbar">
        <li><a href="#">Occasions</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Valentine's Day</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Easter</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Mother's Day</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Father's Day</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Wedding</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Birthday</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Baby</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Cards &amp; Invitations</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Invitations</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Baby</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Weddings</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Announcements</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Holiday</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Canvas Prints</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Full Wrap</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Colour Edge Wrap</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Frame</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Mugs</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">11oz Single Image Mug</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">11oz Double Image Mug</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">11oz Scrapbook Mug</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">11oz Fullwrap Mug</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">14oz Travel Mug</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">17oz Latte Mug</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Device Cases</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Smartphones</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Tablets</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">iPods</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Photo Gifts</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Keychains</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Mousepads</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Playing Cards</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Puzzles</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">T-Shirts</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than read and tweak your code, I wrote a working example with minimal CSS. Hope it helps.

```css
#navbar {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#navbar li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 1em 0 0;
  padding: 0 0 1em;
}

#navbar li ul {
  display: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: .5em 0 0;
  width: 10em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

#navbar li li {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 .5em;
  padding: 0;
}

#navbar>li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul id="navbar">
  <li>
    <a href="#0">Occasions</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#1">Valentine's Day</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#2">Easter</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#3">Mother's Day</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Father's Day</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Wedding</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Birthday</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Baby</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Cards &amp; Invitations</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Invitations</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Baby</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Weddings</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Announcements</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Holiday</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Canvas Prints</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Full Wrap</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Colour Edge Wrap</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Frame</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Mugs</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">11oz Single Image Mug</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">11oz Double Image Mug</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">11oz Scrapbook Mug</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">11oz Fullwrap Mug</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">14oz Travel Mug</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">17oz Latte Mug</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Device Cases</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Smartphones</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Tablets</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">iPods</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Photo Gifts</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Keychains</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Mousepads</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Playing Cards</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Puzzles</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">T-Shirts</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```